# Updating an AutoScalingGroup with a new LaunchConfiguration in boto

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, autoscaling

I have a script that needs to update a named AutoScalingGroup with a new LaunchConfiguration for some new just-created AMI. Unfortunately the documentation isn't good, and I'm tired of trial-and-error. This is what I have so far:

```
build_autoscale_name = "build_autoscaling"
build_autoscale_lc = LaunchConfiguration(
                           ...launch config stuff...
                           , image_id=imid  # new AMI
                           )
as_conn.create_launch_configuration(build_autoscale_lc)
ag = AutoScalingGroup(
            group_name=build_autoscale_name
          , launch_config=build_autoscale_lc
          ...other ASG stuff...
          )
as_conn.create_auto_scaling_group(ag)
```

The latest way this is failing is with:

> Launch Configuration by this name already exists

If I comment out the `create_launch_configuration()` I then get:

> AutoScalingGroup by this name already exists

I see AutoScalingGroup has an `update` method; do I need to perhaps `get_all_groups()` then do update with a new LaunchConfiguration with the same name? Or does it matter if I create a newly-named `LaunchConfiguration` every time (i.e. will I run into some limit)?

Answer (score 8):

I was experiencing a similar problem, when trying to update an existing autoscaling group, and managed to sort it out with the the process you suggested in your original post: using `get_all_groups()` to fetch the autoscaling group, and then `calling update()` on the object after updating the attributes.

Full example:

```
autoscaling_group_name = 'my-test-asg'

launch_config_name = 'my-test-lc'

launch_config = LaunchConfiguration( name=launch_config_name,
                    image_id=image_id,
                    key_name=ssh_key_name,
                    security_groups=security_groups,
                    user_data=user_data,
                    instance_type=instance_type,
                    associate_public_ip_address=associate_public_ip )

as_group = as_conn.get_all_groups(names=[autoscaling_group_name])[0]

setattr(as_group, launch_config_name, launch_config)

as_group.update()
```

Comment: launch_config isnt used in this code after being defined ?

Comment: @Sirex - yes indeed, I've fixed that now (over two years later, lol)

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `boto`, but I can clear few doubts about autoscaling in AWS. To update launch configuration of an autoscaling group you will have to create a new launch configuration and update the launch config for autoscaling group. You can either keep two names for launchconfig. So if the first name is in use then delete the launch config with the second name and create a new one with the second name after that update autoscaling group and same if launchconfig in use has the second name. So, you will have only two launch configs at a time.

Hope I have understood you problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I'll probably try that method with two launch configs. It's a shame this is so clunky!